# LazyColum and component with infinity maximum height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm trying to integrate a Compose view inside an existing XML layout.

This is the structure of the XML with the Composable inside:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView/>

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

At runtime I'm getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.

Any idea about what could be the issue?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you cannot add a `LazyColumn` that has no fixed size into a layout that is itself infinite. The `NestedScrollView` provides no bounds for its children (that's why it's "scrollable"), so anything inside could have infinite height. The `LazyColumn` is essentially a scroll container too, so you want to put an infinite high scroll container in an infinite high scroll container. That's a big no.

Comment: But I can put a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` why I cannot do the same with `LazyColum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use nesting components that can be scrolled in the same direction.

[Lazy layouts in Compose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ANt65eoNhQ&t=896s)

Comment: What if instead of adding the Compose view directly into the XML I will wrap everything inside another fragment added into the XML using a `FragmentContaier`?

Comment: The main point is that as long as the parent of LazyColumn has a fixed length and not same direction nesting layout, the specific method you use doesn't matter.

Comment: Ortak peki iç içe kullanmamız gerekn durumda ne yapmamız gerekiyor Composda onu anlamadım.Dediğini anladım bendede benzer problem var da .Dikeyde kaydırma yapmam lazım aama biryerde de LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid kullanarak grid işlemi yapmaya çalışıyorum direk patlıyor

Comment: `LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid` için sabit bir yükseklik ver